# Storing Result in Array and Substring in Bash

Tags: bash, svn

I have the list of committed files on svn stored in a variable as the following:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
DETAILED_FILES=`svnlook changed -t $TXN $REPOS`
```

`DETAILED_FILES` looks like:

```
U   data0.xml A   data1.xml UU  all_data.xml
```

How can I remove all change type prefixes? such as

```
U   |data0.xml
```

Also, is it possible to store these in an array?

And can I get the full path of these files by `svnlook`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more proper way would be:

```
repos=$1
txn=$2

files=()

while read -r _ f; do
    files+=( "$f" )
done < <(svnlook -t "$txn" "$repos")
```

Mind the quotes! (you used quotes where they are useless—yet harmless—but omitted the mandatory ones!).

Comment: do you if I can get the full path of the committed files by `svnlook`?

Comment: @rz3r0 I don't know `svn` well enough to answer that question. But if you know the full path, it's easy to add it in the array: replace the line `files+=( "$f" )` with `files+=( "/full/path/to/the/files/$f" )`. Don't know whether this is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do:

```
FILES=( $(echo $DETAILED_FILES | cut -c 3-) )
```

Now `FILES` is an array and you can access the array elements by iterating over them:

```
for i in "${FILES[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Explicitly, `${FILES[0]}` will get you the first element, `${FILES[1]}` second and so on.

I am not familiar with `svnlook` so can not answer your second question.